# Screen transition animation with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-transitions

I have different composables with each composable representing a screen. I have used navigation controller for this. How do I add a slide in/out animation on going from one composable (screen) to another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transition animations in navigation compose is being tracked in this feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172112072, so u cannot use at this moment anim, but u can find some tricks in the previous link.

Answer (score 1):

Now we have an official solution for this. Lately [Google Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist) has added a library which provides Compose Animation support for Jetpack Navigation Compose.. Do check it out.

https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/navigation-animation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Android added support for this in `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0-beta02` but you can use it in the latest stable version `2.7.1` as well. Also you will need to set compileSdk to 34 as this library is not compatible with sdk 33 anymore.

Some examples you can find in this [article](https://proandroiddev.com/screen-transition-animations-with-jetpack-navigation-17afdc714d0e) of Alejandro Zurcher.