# android compose navigation how to keep the local state of the previous page?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

in activity stack list, if top activity is translucent, I can see other activity below it,

but compose-navigation is always just render top stack. I can not see other back stack below it.

How to achieve the following route switching effect by compose-navigation ?

[image]

## Note !!!

This has nothing to do with animation, This is the retaining problem of the page local state

### example with compose-Navigation

```
// page_a
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
// balabala
Button(onClick = {
scope.launch{
  while(true){
    delay(3000)
    log('xxx')
  }
}
controller.navigate('anyNewPage')
})
```

when you click button, What will the console output ?

nothing to output, because the state of the page_a is destroyed.

now the question is how to keep the local state of the previous page?

just declare scope outside page_a ? no no no

scope just is one of many local states of pagea and page_a is reusable

like this stack:

```
// stack_top
page_a
page_b
page_a
```

the number of scope should be 2, declare scope outside page_a is not working

Comment: vue-router and react-router are also this,  just render top stack, how to render all stack?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67819672/screen-transition-animation-with-jetpack-compose answer your question? AnimatedNavHost and animated transitions are still experimental in Compose, see the official blog post https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animations-in-navigation-compose-36d48870776b

Comment: the key is render all stack instead of replace render or animation,

Comment: ok, I achieve a router with  render all stack, it can achieve above route switching effect